# How to perform SoftMax on outputs from multiple models?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I wish to classify 8 classes.

Instead of building an 8-class classifier, I build 8 binary classifiers. Each binary classifier differentiates one class from the other three classes. For example,(0 vs 1+2+3+4+5+6+7) and (1 vs 0+2+3+4+5+6+7), etc

How can I run a `SoftMax` function to identify which classifier has predicted 'class 0' with the highest confidence?

[image]
Can anyone help with codes?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by 4 binary classifiers? Le't say you have classes 0,1,2,3. You have a binary classifier for 0/Not_0, another for 1/Not_1, etc. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @CrazyBrazilian yes, I will rephase it

Comment: I apologize but it does not seem right. Based on what you are saying, you have only one classifier that predicts 0. You can't use softmax. softmax is basically a normalization for your multi class classification to make sure probabilities sum up to 1

Comment: @CrazyBrazilian I kind of add a diagram to help explain what I wish to achieve

Comment: @Leo do yo have 4 binary classifiers or 8 binary classifiers ?

Comment: @Andrey Thank you. My own task is 8, the diagram was added afterwards. I rephrased the question to avoid your misunderstanding.

Comment: Based on your new diagram, you just have a multi class classifier. Nothing else.

Comment: You say you want to classify 8 classes and then later that each classifier differentiates one class from the other three classes ? I'm lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a different diagram

[image]

Now let's look at what you have and see if you need a softmax.

First of all, my assumption is that your classifiers are exactly the same.

Let's supposed that you push a record thru your model and you get the following

P0=0.4
P_NOT_0=P1+P2+P3=0.6

P1=0.3
P_NOT_1=P0+P2+P3=0.7

P2=0.2
P_NOT_2=P0+P1+P3=0.8

P3=0.1
P_NOT_3=P0+P1+P2=0.9

You might think that I "faked" the numbers to make P0+P1+P2+P3=1, but I did not. There is no other possible output.

If you don't believe me, do this. Pick a value for P0 and replace it in all the formulas. Then do the same for P1, P2 and P3. You will see that unless P0+P1+P2+P3=1, you can't make all formulas true.

Basically if all classifiers are the same, the value of P0, P1, P2 and P3 in all formulas is the same.

Now, back to your question. You don't need a softmax because P1+P2+P3+P4 is already normalized.

I don't know exactly what you are doing but if you are just doing a multi class classification model, why not have one output per class and than finally use the softmax?

Do you still need help writing the code?

@andrey ( in the comments ) has brought a few good points also. First, there is always an error and second if you are using a sigmoid as output of each classifier, they are not really probabilities but the idea is still applicable.

Comment: oh sorry, just noticed that now you changed to 8 classifiers, not 4 classifiers. Again, if all those classifiers are the same, the contribution of, let's say, P0 to the probability of each classifier is exactly the same

Comment: please adjust P_NOT_3. And I doubt that in real life p0 + p1 + p2 + p3 equal to 1: classifiers will not predict probabilities ideally

Comment: thanks @Andrew. that is right ! I did not want to get into too much detail regarding the real meaning of the sigmoid output ( assuming he is using one )

Comment: I would add a small error to p0, p1, p2, p3 so that they don't sum up to 1. It would highlight that the question is not correct

Comment: yup ! i agree 100% ! I was trying to give a high level example.. but i'm still not sure what is the end goal.. it seems just a simple multi class classification